# Apache ignite as shared drive for storing and retrieve files

Tags: file, ignite

My requirement is to take out the shared drive across our web application and handle file sharing using Apache Ignite (kind of file sharing service). In that way we don't need to worry about whether that shared drive is accessible and also it is seemless across applications.
 What do you guys suggest?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only relevant part of Apache Ignite was `IGFS`, and we have recently discontinued it. I recommend using something dedicated for file sharing.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but what is the reason for your decision ? Also we are also planning to use it's core usage such as data grid as well. So I felt it is multipurpose.

Comment: It's not enough to put data in RAM and get a significant performance boost. The rest of the APIs have to be optimized for in-memory usage and minimize data shuffling. With IGFS it was all about caching, Hadoop APIs were not optimized for Ignite as a shared file system. Ignite still might be used for your use case but remember that the files will be stored as key-value records in RAM.